# Oracle request (how to import data excel to oracle)

Tags: oracle, import-from-excel

What are the best and/or easiest methods for importing data from Excel (.xls) into an Oracle database?

Please, kindly clarify with any code examples you can.

Comment: An idea is to use the IDE. Toad and SQL Developer has import excel option. Just right click the table and select import option.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common way for importing data from Excel to Oracle Db is to export the contents as a CSV and use [SQL*Loader](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) to import it into the table.

The easiest way however, is to use an IDE as mentioned in the comments like TOAD or SQL Developer (which is my favourite Oracle DBM tool).

See [this article](http://oracleebusinesssuite.wordpress.com/2007/06/27/import-of-an-excel-or-any-other-file-external-data-into-oracle/) for more alternative ways.

Comment: Oracle XE has a browser based wizard (apex) that will do everything as well - including creating lookup tables and surrogate keys with the sequence and necessary trigger.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use perl to read the excel spreadsheet and insert the values from the spreadsheet into the db.  Take a look at DBD::Oracle and Spreadsheet::ParseExcel in CPAN.